# In what order are After Effects layer effects applied?

Tags: after-effects

Pardon the noob question – If I have say a "brightness" effect and a "sharpen" effect appearing in this order (first is on top of the other), will "brightness" be applied first, then "sharpen"? or the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works the way you suspected it would. Applied effects on a layer work from top to bottom, same with adjustment-layers and layer-modes applying from top to bottom.